# JavaScript Array conflicting with React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have three checkboxes that when selected fire a function. I'm using React-Bootstrap and my code is like this:

```
    let departmentArray = ([]);
    
      function handleCheck(val) {

        //DEPARTMENT ARRAY LOAD
        const index = departmentArray.indexOf(val);
        if (index > -1) {
          departmentArray.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          departmentArray.push(val);
        }

        //REACT COMPONENT 
        if (val === "Maintenance") {
          setMaintCheck(!maintCheck);
        } else if (val === "Process") {
          setProcCheck(!procCheck);
        } else if (val === "Toolroom") {
          setToolCheck(!toolCheck);
        }

      }; 

  return (
    <>
       <Form.Check name={'department'} onClick={(e) => {handleCheck("Maintenance")}} checked={maintCheck} />
       <Form.Check name={'department'} onClick={(e) => {handleCheck("Process");}} checked={procCheck} />
       <Form.Check name={'department'} onClick={(e) => {handleCheck("Toolroom");}} checked={toolCheck} />
    </>
  )
```

The state of the checkboxes works with this code, but the array ***departmentArray*** does not work if the code underneath *//REACT COMPONENT* is present. If I remove these lines, the ***departmentArray*** loads correctly. I have no idea why the two would be affecting each other.

Comment: At the very least you are missing a curly brace } to close your function handleCheck. React component function names should also be uppercase (HandleCheck not handleCheck).

Comment: Instead of using `indexOf` to check if an Array contains a value use `if(departmentArray.includes(val)` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The departmentArray seems to be a normal var for React, when the code that is under `// REACT COMPONENT` executes the component rerenders and departmentArray reinitializes to []. You can put departmentArray out of the component as a constant or declare it as a state var for the component reacts to its changes

This is what I mean:

```js
const departmentArray = []

const component = (props) => {

   const loadData = () => {
      // get data from somewhere
      departmentArray.push(...)
   }
   return <></>
}
```

Or you can declare departmentArray as a state var:

```js
const [departmentArray, setDepartmentArray] = useState([])

const loadDepartments = () => {
   // load data
}

useEffect(loadDeparments, [])
```

Comment: Changing the departmentArray to `const departmentArray = ([]);` doesn't resolve the issue if that's what you mean, and I also need to be able to preload the array with data, hence the use of `let`.

I understand what the problem is now, but I'm unclear how I can use `useState` to with an array like this. Are you able to elaborate?

Comment: @NathanField I didn't mean just change it to a const but declare it out of the component, that way React will not reinitialize in every rerender. Also `departmentArray` is an array and you are updating it using array methods `push` and `splice` so, it's safe to declare it as a constant cause you are not modifying the variable itself